# how to retrieve no of comment?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

```
items table(the users will select and store into mysql

itemID | name   | item 
1      | Mary   | pants, jeans
2      | John   | jacket, shirt
3      | Jack   | jacket, shirt

description table 

descID | item         
1      | jacket, shirt
2      | pants, jeans  
3      | dress, jeans 

comment table (retrieve the no of comments made)
commentId| item          | comment
1        | jacket        | great
2        | jacket        | nice
3        | jeans         | comfortable
```

How do I retrieve the no of comments from the comment table example, John logged in. It should retrieve 2.

So far I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(comment)) AS comment
FROM comment co
INNER JOIN item i
WHERE co.item = i.item;
```

Comment: What's the DDL? (DESCRIBE the tables)

Comment: select count(*) from comment

Comment: it's not clear how tables are related with other.

Comment: I think you need to rethink the organization of your tables.  You shouldn't be storing values like "jacket, shirt" in a single field. It makes your current task at hand much harder.

Comment: can you atleast specify how are they related?

Comment: @screamout - i think its better to change your table structure first

Comment: They may not be strings, they could be a `SET`: hence the request for the DDL

Answer (score 1):

You should be relating your tables using foreign keys, not text strings. The answer is to fix your table design.

It appears you want a many-to-many relationship between users and item. This requires another table to store the many-to-many association.

Users:

```
ID     | name
1      | Mary
2      | John
3      | Jack
```

Items:

```
ID     | description         
1      | jacket
2      | pants  
3      | dress
4      | shirt
5      | jeans
```

UserItemAssoc:

```
UserID | ItemID
1      | 2
1      | 5
2      | 1
2      | 4
3      | 1
3      | 4
```

Comments:

```
ID       | itemID        | comment
1        | 1             | great
2        | 1             | nice
3        | 5             | comfortable
```

Your Query would then be:

```
select count(distinct c.ID) from 
Users as u JOIN UserItemAssoc as uaa on (u.id = uaa.userID)
JOIN Items as i on (i.ID = uaa.itemID)
JOIN Comments as c on (c.itemID = i.ID)
WHERE u.Name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.comment) AS commentCount 
FROM comment c 
INNER JOIN item i ON FIND_IN_SET(c.item, i.item) 
WHERE i.name = 'John';
```